# how to reverse the color of row legend in heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I would like to reverse the default annotation for row:

```
library(NMF) #any other packages for this task are welcome
car<-cars
car$p<-sample(1:600, 50)*0.0001
aheatmap(as.matrix(cars[,1:2,drop=FALSE]),annRow =car[,"p",drop=FALSE])
```

[image]

As you can see in row annotation, the 0 represents white color and larger number the deeper green. I would like to see the smaller p, the deeper green (or grey).

Moreover, if that is possible, the p larger than 0.05 would present only white color.

It is really challenging for me. Thanks for any helps or comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colors using the `annColors` parameter.  This reverses the order of green-white:

```
aheatmap(as.matrix(cars[,1:2,drop=FALSE]),annRow =car[,"p",drop=FALSE], annColors="-Greens")
```

To make anything above p=.05 white, you could subset your data to make anything above that value `NA` and do the same coloring:

```
car$p[car$p>.05]<-NA
aheatmap(as.matrix(cars[,1:2,drop=FALSE]),annRow =car[,"p",drop=FALSE], annColors="-Greens")
```

[image]

Comment: That's GREAT, Thanks jalapic